# Use widevine library in swift

Tags: swift, drm, widevine

i have a technical question.
I have integrated the widevine library inside my swift project.
I have linked with bridging header the objective-c library.
The problem is that the library use:

```
WViOsApiStatus WV_Initialize(const WViOsApiStatusCallback callback, NSDictionary *settings );
```

where  `WViOsApiStatusCallback` is:

```
typedef WViOsApiStatus (*WViOsApiStatusCallback)( WViOsApiEvent event, NSDictionary *attributes );
```

In objective-c i write this code in .m file:

```
WViOsApiStatus WidevineCallback( WViOsApiEvent event, NSDictionary *attributes );

@implementation WidevineHelper

-myFunc(){
  WV_Initialize(WidevineCallback, configuratioWV);
}

WViOsApiStatus WidevineCallback( WViOsApiEvent event, NSDictionary *attributes )
{

 //some code
}
```

In Swift i have any idea to convert the objective-c code

Thank you
Andrea

____ ADDITIONAL INFO____

```
class WidevineHelper: NSObject {

typealias WViOsApiStatusCallback = (event: WViOsApiEvent, attributes:  NSDictionary? ) -> WViOsApiStatus
var testCallaback : WViOsApiStatusCallback =  {(event: WViOsApiEvent, attributes:  NSDictionary?) ->WViOsApiStatus in


}

func testfunction(){
    var test = WV_Initialize(callback: testCallaback , settings: [NSObject : AnyObject]())
}
}
```

I try this; it seems correct but compiler says:

/path/WidevineHelper.swift:20:20: Cannot invoke 'WV_Initialize' with an argument list of type '(callback: WViOsApiStatusCallback, settings: [NSObject : AnyObject])'

The widevine method declaration in objective-c is:

```
typedef WViOsApiStatus (*WViOsApiStatusCallback)( WViOsApiEvent event, NSDictionary *attributes );

WViOsApiStatus WV_Initialize(const WViOsApiStatusCallback callback, NSDictionary *settings );
```

I'm going crazy with porting in swift. So sad..

Comment: use xcode 7 beta. In swift 2.0, you can use function pointer easily.

Answer (score 0):

use xcode 7 beta. In swift 2.0, you can use function pointer easily.

```
WV_Initialize({ (event, attr) -> WViOsApiStatus in
    return WViOsApiStatus_OK
}, options)
```